# Matplotlib plot dates on x axis with equal spacing

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I am trying to plot date on x axis using subplots, but spacing on x axis is too overcrowded and impossible to read. How do I make this spacing equally viable and readable.

below is my code:

```
def plot_time_series(area):
    df_area =df.loc[df.area== str(area)]
    df_area.reset_index(inplace = True)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
    formatter = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
    ax.title.set_text(market)
    p1 , = plt.plot(df_area['index'], (df_area.feature1 * 1000), color='#15B01A', label='Feature 1')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30, labelsize=10)
    plt.title(str(market))
    p2 , = plt.plot(df_area['index'], df_area.feature_2, color='red', label='feature_2')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    lgd  = plt.legend(handles=[p1, p2], title='Legend', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
```

Plot currently generated:

[image]

**I need to plot dates on x axis with equal spacing and visually readable. How to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

I have used mdates with majorlocator and majorformatter to achieve this, updated function below:

```
def plot_time_series(area):
    df_area =df.loc[df.area== str(area)]
    df_area.reset_index(inplace = True)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval = 18))
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30, labelsize=10)
    p1 , = plt.plot(df_area['index'], (df_area.feature1 * 1000), color='#15B01A', label='Feature 1')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30, labelsize=10)
    plt.title(str(market))
    p2 , = plt.plot(df_area['index'], df_area.feature_2, color='red', label='feature_2')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    lgd  = plt.legend(handles=[p1, p2], title='Legend', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
```